# Load models from other packages in MEAN.IO

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

In following project structure I have a dependency between 2 custom MEAN.IO packages

/custom

- package1

  - server

    - controllers
    - routes
    - models

      - model1.js
- package2

  - server

    - controllers
    - routes
    - models

      - model2.js

model1 and model2 are both used in their own controllers, but I would like to implement an algorithm which uses both.

My first guess would be:

```
var Model2 = mongoose.model('Model2')
```

But this returns an error:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Model2".
```

My second guess was to include model again:

```
var model = require('../../../package2/server/models/model2'),
Meeting = mongoose.model('Meeting'), ...
```

Yet still no luck, is there anybody who knows how to include models from another package in mean.io?

Comment: You can do it the way article is using user model. https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/core/articles/server/models/article.js

Comment: The article controller does not include the User model, it just populates the 'user' field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Each of the model object is handled by mongoose, and since mongoose is global, you can just call a schema of it.

You have to add your model to mongoose using  mongoose.model(modelName, schema)

in your model.js do

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
Schema    = mongoose.Schema,
crypto    = require('crypto'),
      _   = require('lodash');
var Model1Schema = new Schema({ ... });
mongoose.model('Model1', ModelSchema);
```

in your controller you can call it this way

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Model1 = mongoose.model('Model1'),
_ = require('lodash');
```

check for more here 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: The problem is with MEAN.IO, not with mongoose. I registered the schema's correctly in my models, but they were not loaded at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems that Model2 hasn't been initialized by the time

```
var Model2 = mongoose.model('Model2')
```

was executed. I think mean.io is loading the packages alphabetically that's why Model2 hasn't been loaded during Model1's initialization. What you can do as a work around is to use

```
mongoose.model('Model2')
```

in your model functions repeatedly instead of putting it in a variable.

An example would be

```
Model1Schema.statics.findUsingModel2 = function(model2Id,cb){
    mongoose.model('Model2').find({_id : model2Id}).exec(cb);
}
```